# How to correctly use mmap() and newBufferWithBytesNoCopy together?

Tags: gpu, posix, metal, mmap, mtlbuffer

While generating a texture from an `MTLBuffer` created from `mmap()` via [`newBufferWithBytesNoCopy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433382-newbufferwithbytesnocopy), if the number of pages requested by the `len` argument to `mmap` is larger than the number of pages of size of the file, the `mmap` call succeeds, and the `newBufferWithBytesNoCopy` message does not result in a `nil` return or error, but when I pass the buffer to the GPU to copy the data to an `MTLTexture`, the following is printed to the console, and all GPU commands fail to perform any action:

> Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Internal Error (IOAF code -536870211)

Here is code to demonstrate the problem:

```
static id<MTLDevice> Device;
static id<MTLCommandQueue> Queue;
static id<MTLTexture> BlockTexture[3];
#define TEX_LEN_1 1 // These are all made 1 in this question for simplicity
#define TEX_LEN_2 1
#define TEX_LEN_4 1
#define TEX_SIZE ((TEX_LEN_1<<10)+(TEX_LEN_2<<11)+(TEX_LEN_4<<12))
#define PAGE_ALIGN(S) ((S)+PAGE_SIZE-1&~(PAGE_SIZE-1))
int main(void) {
    if (!(Queue = [Device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() newCommandQueue]))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    @autoreleasepool {
        const id<MTLBuffer> data = ({
            void *const map = ({
                NSFileHandle *const file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:[NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"Content" ofType:nil]];
                if (!file)
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                mmap(NULL, TEX_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, file.fileDescriptor, 0);
            });
            if (map == MAP_FAILED)
                return errno;
            [Device newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:map length:PAGE_ALIGN(TEX_SIZE) options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared deallocator:^(void *const ptr, const NSUInteger len){
                munmap(ptr, len);
            }];
        });
        if (!data)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        const id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer = [Queue commandBuffer];
        const id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> encoder = [buffer blitCommandEncoder];
        if (!encoder)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        {
            MTLTextureDescriptor *const descriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor new];
            descriptor.width = descriptor.height = 32;
            descriptor.mipmapLevelCount = 6;
            descriptor.textureType = MTLTextureType2DArray;
            descriptor.storageMode = MTLStorageModePrivate;
            const enum MTLPixelFormat format[] = {MTLPixelFormatR8Unorm, MTLPixelFormatRG8Unorm, MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm};
            const NSUInteger len[] = {TEX_LEN_1, TEX_LEN_2, TEX_LEN_4};
            for (NSUInteger i = 3, off = 0; i--;) {
                descriptor.pixelFormat = format[i];
                const NSUInteger l = descriptor.arrayLength = len[i];
                const id<MTLTexture> texture = [Device newTextureWithDescriptor:descriptor];
                if (!texture)
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                const NSUInteger br = 32<<i, bi = 1024<<i;
                for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < l; off += bi)
                    [encoder copyFromBuffer:data sourceOffset:off sourceBytesPerRow:br sourceBytesPerImage:bi sourceSize:(const MTLSize){32, 32, 1} toTexture:texture destinationSlice:j++ destinationLevel:0 destinationOrigin:(const MTLOrigin){0}];
                [encoder generateMipmapsForTexture:BlockTexture[i] = texture];
            }
        }
        [encoder endEncoding];
        [buffer commit];
    }
    // Rest of code to initialize application (omitted)
}
```

In this case, the command will fail if the size of the actual `Content` file is less than 4097 bytes, assuming a 4096 page size. What is the most strange is that neither the `mmap()` nor the `newBufferWithBytesNoCopy` fails in this case, and any/all subsequent GPU calls also fail.

I thought `mmap()` space beyond the file was just valid 0 memory. Why is this apparently not the case here? At the very least, how can I detect GPU execution errors or invalid buffers like this to handle them gracefully, besides manually checking if the file is too small? Is this a bug in the OS or are the functions being utilized incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code or the usage of `mmap()` here. The problem is that by design, the pages of a mapped file that lie beyond the end of the file will [result in a `SIGBUS` if accessed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76471589/16217248).

The GPU errors are the result of the GPU performing the access violation that would result in a `SIGBUS`.

The solution is to use `fstat()` to ensure the texture file is large enough before trying to copy the data to the textures.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that by design, the pages of a mapped file that lie beyond the end of the file will result in a SIGBUS if accessed.

That is the behaviour on Linux kernel. MacOS man page about mmap says:

> If length is not a multiple of the pagesize, the mapped region may extend past the specified range. Any extension beyond the end of the mapped object will be zero-filled.