# How is mmap() supposed to behave if the requested mapping size is larger than the file?

Tags: c, file, memory, posix, mmap

To my understanding, `mmap()` is for bulk loading of files into memory. As such they can be used as such:

```
// Assuming PAGE_SIZE == 4096
int fd = open("/some/large/resource", O_RDONLY);
void *buffer = mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
// Use buffer
munmap(buffer, 8192);
```

That should achieve similar effect to, and be ostensibly faster than, this:

```
int fd = open("/some/large/resource", O_RDONLY);
void *buffer = malloc(8196);
read(fd, buffer, 8196);
// Use buffer
free(buffer);
```

What would happen if `/some/large/resource` was in fact, not 8192 bytes, but 4096 bytes. One entire page of memory smaller? For the second case, `read()` would return 4096 indicating that many bytes were successfully read, and the rest of the buffer would be indeterminate but valid writing space.

**But what would (should?) happen in the `mmap()` case?** And does what happens depend on the `flags`, i.e., if I used `MAP_PRIVATE` instead of `MAP_SHARED`? Would the memory in the next page be inaccessible? Would the memory be accessible but indeterminate as in the `malloc()`/`read()` case? Would the memory be zeroed out?

**Disclaimer:** This is a followup to [How to correctly use mmap() and newBufferWithBytesNoCopy together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74454489/16217248) I am asking this new question to determine if the problem described in the older question is an `mmap()` problem or some other problem.

Comment: What does the man page tell you?

Comment: For reference: [`mmap()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing a page in mmap region but completely out of file size will cause a bus error.
The mmap function will succeed, returning a pointer which seems right.
But if you access a out-of-file page, you will get a bus error.
In man mmap:

> SIGBUS Attempted access to a page of the buffer that lies beyond the end of the mapped file.

Comment: Is it possible to circumvent that? I.e., an argument or setting that would make the data valid 0 memory instead of triggering a BUS error?

Comment: @user16217248 I didn't find a direct way to do that. Perhaps you can do it manually. e.g. You can mmap one region with least pages the file needs. And then mmap with MAP_ANONYMOUS and  MAP_FIXED to concatenate two regions and make it behave like what you want.

Comment: Is there any way to find out where the pages are valid? Aside from separately measuring the size of the file?

Comment: @user16217248 I didn't find an easier way by now.