# How can I determine if all mapped pages while using mmap() are valid?

Tags: c, memory, error-handling, posix, mmap

I learned that pages allocated by `mmap()` can be unusable, even if the call returned success. **For example** if [a file is being mapped and the `len` passed to `mmap()` is sufficiently larger than the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76471589/16217248). In that case, any pages beyond the pages used by the file, even if within the requested size, will yield a `SIGBUS` if they are attempted to be used.

Is there any way to directly determine if **all** the bytes from the beginning of the mapping up to `len` will be accessible safely or not? Can I do this **besides** manually measuring the length of the file, or setting up a `SIGBUS` handler, or otherwise (exhaustively) checking if any of the reason(s) a page would be inaccessible have been met?

```
// Assuming PAGE_SIZE == 4096
int fd = open("file", O_RDONLY);
void *buffer = mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
// Is there any way to determine if reading bytes 4093-8192 will cause a bus error?
// Besides measuring if the size of the file is greater than 4092?
```

Rather than checking the file size to determine if any pages *would be* unavailable *because the file is too small*, can I *directly* determine if any pages *are* unavailable for *any reason*?

Comment: Use `fstat` to get the file's size. Then, use `ftruncate` to grow/shrink the file. Then, do the `mmap`.

Comment: @user16217248 What's wrong with measuring the size of the file?  You already have an open file descriptor, and compared to the time it takes for the system to do the memory-mapping gyrations necessary to do the actual mapping and then page in the file data, one extra access to the already-cached-because-you-just-opened-it file metadata to get the length will literally be unmeasurable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So the *canonical way* is to just check if the file is separately large enough?

Comment: @user16217248 Pretty much.  If you're on Linux, run something like `strace -o /tmp/out.txt ls`.  You'll see the run-time linker loading all the libraries the `ls` executable needs with a bunch of `open()`/`fstat()`/`mmap()` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way would be to just use `fstat()` to measure the size of the file anyway, and fail if the file is too small. There is no more *'direct'* way to query the availability of pages, and no need for one, as the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) shows, under *Signals*, that the only way for `SIGBUS` to occur is if the file is too small:

> ```
> SIGBUS Attempted access to a page of the buffer that lies beyond
>       the end of the mapped file.  For an explanation of the
>       treatment of the bytes in the page that corresponds to the
>       end of a mapped file that is not a multiple of the page
>       size, see NOTES.
> ```

The following code is an example of how `mmap()` could be safely used:

```
#define PAGE_ALIGN(S) ((S)+PAGE_SIZE-1&~(PAGE_SIZE-1))
#define EXPECTED_SIZE /* ... */

int fd = open("file", O_RDONLY);
struct stat statbuf;
if (fstat(fd, &statbuf) || PAGE_ALIGN(statbuf.st_size) < EXPECTED_SIZE)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
void *mapping = mmap(NULL, EXPECTED_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
if (mapping == MAP_FAILED)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
```